# Open Android Add New Contact Screen

Tags: javascript, android, ios, web

I Want to open a Android/IOS's Add new contact Screen on a button click of a website.
Similar to WhatsApp's Add to Contact button

I want to open this Page on button click
[Screen I want to open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxikF.png)

I tried using ChatGPT and Bard but none of them worked